# How do I fix the Y axis? What is this problem?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have this code:

```
b = np.array([['a',2,3],['b',1,3],['c',4,4],['d',5,6],['e',5,5],['f',6,6]])
a= pd.DataFrame(b)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

plt.bar(a[0],a[1],color='r')
```

It produces this graph:

[image]

As you can see, there is something wrong with the Y axis. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: No, I can't see the problem. What do you want the chart to look like instead?

Comment: The value for 'a' should be 2 right? But the y axis 2 has replaced itself with the origin.

Comment: Check `a.dtypes` - hint, your numbers are objects.

Comment: This hint worked! Can you please elaborate the problem in my code being object and plotting them is wrong or something? Anyhow, it worked, thanks for the tip. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: The numpy array is homogenous and casting the ints to strings since you're mixing ints and strings. Plotting strings is causing the unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is treating all elements of the dataframe `a` as `object`, i.e., anything other than a number. You can convert them when plotting with:

```
plt.bar(a[0], a[1].astype(int), color='r')
```

This was the case because numpy cast every element to a string, since it can't handle multiple types in an array, IIRC. If you replace your creation of `b` with:

```
b = [['a',2,3],['b',1,3],['c',4,4],['d',5,6],['e',5,5],['f',6,6]]
```

Then you don't need to convert, as this is the output of `a.types`:

```
0    object
1     int64
2     int64
dtype: object
```